# How to pass arguments to a BackGroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, sapi

```
Imports SpeechLib

Public Class Form1
    Public vox = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")

    Private Sub cmdSpeak_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSpeak.Click
        Dim text2 As String = "Hello , This is a Text. Hello , This is a Text."
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdPause_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPause.Click
        vox.pause()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim SVEPhoneme As Integer = 64
        vox.EventInterests = SVEPhoneme
        vox.AlertBoundary = SVEPhoneme
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdResume_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdResume.Click
        vox.resume()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        vox.Speak(Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I pass text2 to vox.speak?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `cmdSpeak_Click`, pass text2 as a parameter to RunWorkerAsync

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(text2)
```

In `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork`, retrieve the value of the parameter

```
vox.Speak(DirectCast(e.Argument, String), SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)
```

Comment: Sorry about this dumb question but how do I add text2 as a parameter in cmdSpeakClick   ?

Comment: Like this `Private Sub cmdSpeak_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs, ByVal text2 As String) Handles cmdSpeak.Click`   ??

Comment: Replace your line `BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` with my line `BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(text2)`

Comment: By the way, How do I stop the audio once I play or pause it ?

Comment: I wouldn't know. That would be grounds for a new question.